# Counting ways to line up for a family photo.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Question:
A family lines up for a photograph. In each of the following situations, how many ways are there for the family to line up so that the mother is next to at least one of her daughters?

### The family consists of two parents, three daughters and four sons.

So I tried to solve this using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle but got stuck at the very end step.
The formula I used is: 
|A ∪ B ∪ C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A ∩ B| - |B ∩ C| - |A ∩ C| + |A ∩ B ∩ C|

Ways for mom to be next to first daughter + Ways for mom to be next to second daughter + Ways for mom to be next to third daughter - Ways for mom to be next to first and second daughter - Ways for mom to be next to first and third daughter - Ways for mom to be next to second and third daughter + Ways for mom to the next to all 3 daughters

I was able to calculate everything except for |A ∩ B ∩ C|. How do we arrange the mom and 3 daughters in this case? Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** I have $(2⋅8!)$ ways for the mom to be next to one daughter. There are $3$ daughters so we have $3⋅2⋅8!$ ways. And then $(2⋅7!)$ ways for each time a mom is between any 2 daughters, that makes $(3⋅2⋅7!)$ in total. Looks like there's $0$ ways for the mom to be next to all $3$ daughters, so I suppose the answer is $(3⋅2⋅8!) - (3⋅2⋅7!)$.

Comment: I think that should be zero because the family has to line up in straight line therefore nother cannot be next to all the 3 daughters at same time.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should show your attempt so that we can check whether your calculations are correct.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Basically I have (2⋅8!) ways for the mom to be next to one daughter. There are 3 daughters so we have 3⋅2⋅8! ways. And then (2⋅7!) ways for each time a mom is between any 2 daughters, that makes (3⋅2⋅7!) in total. Looks like there's 0 way for the mom to be next to all 3 daughters, so I suppose the answer is (3⋅2⋅8!) - (3⋅2⋅7!)

Comment: You have solved the problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is easier to construct the ways of arranging where **no daughter** is beside the mother:

- All arrangements of $2$ parents, $3$ daughters, $4$ sons: $\color{blue}{9!}$
- First line up parents and sons: $(2+4)! = \color{blue}{6!}$
- Each arrangement of these $6$ people produce $7$ possible "slots" where to place the daughters: $\color{green}{7}$
- The $\color{green}{2}$ slots left and right to the mother are not allowed: $\Rightarrow \color{green}{7-2} = \color{green}{5}$ slot
- Distribute $\color{blue}{3}$ daughters (permutations not considered) across the "allowed" $\color{green}{5}$ slots $s_1,\ldots , s_5$: $s_1+ \cdots + s_5 = 3$: $\binom{\color{green}{5}+\color{blue}{3}-1}{\color{blue}{3}} = \color{blue}{\binom 73}$ (this can be seen as [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))
- The $3$ daughters can be arranged among themselves: $\color{blue}{3!}$

All together

$$\color{blue}{9! - 6! \cdot \binom 73  \cdot 3!}$$

Comment: Doing it the way the OP suggested is actually easier, but your answer is correct.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: That's why I wrote "maybe". :-)

Comment: I was thinking of doing this too. But wasn't sure which approach is faster. I think yours works better.